# Stretching a curly bracket to get better vertical symmetry

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, amsmath, brackets, vertical

As can be seen in the following MWE,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
        a&=\frac{b}{c} \\
        a&=e
    \end{aligned}
    \right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

which compiles to

[image]

, due to the difference in height, given by the fraction, of the two equations, the `a`s' position with respect to the brace's margins isn't symmetrical.

Can the bracket be automatically stretched/enlarged in a way such that it looks symmetrical?

Thank you for your help, it is very appreciated.

Comment: Add `\vphantom{\frac{b}{c}}` before `e`?

Comment: @marmot, it works, nice trick, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't get your MWE run through, but with a "regular" document class such as article it does run through. One standard trick is to add a `\vphantom`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
        a&=\frac{b}{c} \\
        a&=\vphantom{\frac{b}{c}}e
    \end{aligned}
    \right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note also that `mathtools` has several specialized commands/environments for similar scenarios, such as `dcases`.

Comment: Edited the question, now it should work properly. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

Here are three possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
        a&=\frac{b}{c} \\
        a&=e\vphantom{\frac{b}{c_k}}%\\[-1ex]\mbox{}
    \end{aligned}
    \right.
\end{equation*}
\bigskip

\begin{equation*}
    \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
        a&=\smash[t]{\frac{b}{c}} \\
        a&=e
    \end{aligned}
    \right.
\end{equation*}
\bigskip

\begin{equation*}\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{2ex}
    \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
        a&= \frac{b}{c} \\
        a&=e \bigstrut[b]
    \end{aligned}
    \right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]